# How to tell when a file transfer has completed (Server to Client)

Tags: .net, ftpwebrequest

I am pulling a file from an ftp server and I'm having trouble feeling comfortable with my method of verifying the transfer was completed successfully.

It feels like there must be a more concrete way of detecting a successful transfer.  Any ideas?

My Code:

```
            var request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(ftpFilePath);

            request.KeepAlive = false;
            request.UseBinary = true;
            request.UsePassive = false;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Username", "Password");
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    contents = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }

            //Check to see if transfer was successful
            if (response.StatusDescription.StartsWith("2"))
                transferSuccessful = true;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the `FtpWebResponse.StatusCode` for success.  e.g. `FtpStatusCode.ClosingData`

Comment: The FtpWebResponse.StatusCode results in FtpStatusCode.ClosingData after the transfer though.

Comment: Oh! But that looks fine.  I just read the Summary for that status code: *Specifies that the server is closing the data connection and that the requested file action was successful.*

Comment: If you change FtpStatusCode.CommandOK to FtpStatusCode.ClosingData in your answer, I'll accept it.